# Listar Categorias e Subcategorias no SIte - Wordpress

Tags: html5, wordpress, wordpress-theme, taxonomia

Atualmente estou com um projeto de site, e tenho uma lista de taxonomias Wordpress, desse modo:

-- Motores (pai)

--- Motores Monofásicos (filho)

--- Motores Trifásicos (filho)

Queria saber como que faço para criar uma lista HTML no Estilo:

- Motores Elétricos
  - Motor Monofásico
  - Motor Trifásico

Meu Código atualmente esta pegando todas as taxonomias e criando uma lista direta sem SubCategorias:

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $terms = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' =>'categoria',
        'hide_empty' => false
    ));

    foreach($terms as $term){  ?>
        <li>
            <div class="menu-link"><a href="?taxonomy=<?= $term -> slug ?>"><?= $term -> name ?> </a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </li>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
</ul>
```

Queria conseguir pegar as subcategorias através da categoria pai.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se o código abaixo pode lhe ajudar:

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $terms = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' =>'categoria',
        'hide_empty' => false
    ));

    foreach($terms as $term){  ?>
        <li>
            <div class="menu-link"><a href="?taxonomy=<?= $term -> slug ?>"><?= $term -> name ?> </a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <ul>
            <?=
            $term_id = $term->term_id;
            $term_children = get_term_children( $term_id, 'categoria' );
            foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
                $termC = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
                echo '<li><a href="?taxonomy=<?= $termC->slug ?>">'.$termC->name.'</a></li>';
            }
            ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
</ul>
```